# (be + to + verb) Grammar

Tags: grammar, verbs

This question destroys my mind so finally I want to know the answer.

> All I have to do is + **to** + verb

or

> All I have to do is + verb

Which one is correct, and can't the wrong one be correct informally?

Comment: If the Everly Brothers had sung "Whenever I want you, all I have to do is **to** dream," it would have ruined the meter of the line. And to what end? Merely to make explicit an infinitive marker that everyone recognized as implicit anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second option is the more correct structure.

To explain it as simply as possible, you have *to do* in the middle of the sentence already. *To do* is an infinitive verb because the unsuffixed action word *do* is preceded by the preposition *to* (which is actually part of the infinitive verb, not just preceding it).

With that, you are now wondering if the verb at the end of the sentence should also be infinitive. It shouldn't simply because the previous infinitive verb, *to do*, already includes the preposition *to*, therefore the last verb doesn't need it.

I see this as a simple example of how English tends to reduce repetitive words as much as possible. In your first example, *to* is found before both verbs. But since that's repetitive, the *to* can be removed from the second verb and essentially shared from the first verb.

Comment: Do you have a source that says that redundancy is erroneous?  The double to-infinitive is common.

Comment: @deadrat Unfortunately I don't have a specific source for this, but I do have an example using another situation: a simple listing structure. _I read lots of books, lots of newspapers, and lots of magazines_ can be simplified to _I read lots of books, newspapers, and magazines_. Redundancy is eliminated for conciseness. Note that I never claimed redundancy to be erroneous.

Comment: Perhaps I misconstrued "the correct structure" in the (original) first sentence of your answer.  But conciseness is a matter style, not grammar.

Comment: @Adam: in my answer I show (admittedly in a smallish sample) that the 'to' is used in about 20% of cases. It would appear that it is used. On what do you base your assertion that it is less "correct"?

Comment: @Adam if we don't use the second "to" because of the first one , so what do you think about `All i do is + verb` or `All i do is + **to** + verb` ?

Answer (score 2):

The second (without 'to') is more common, but both are grammatical.

GloWBe (The Corpus of Global Web-based English) has 210 instances without 'to' and 52 with 'to'.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's easier if we assume that this sentence is "cut down" versions of the [hypothetical]...

1a: All I have to do is **I have to** finish it soon.

Sometimes native speakers will delete the repeatation, it's not a big problem.