# be + to + verb and be + verb

Tags: grammar, verbs

What's the difference between the following sentences?

> All I wanted **was + to + break** your walls
>
> All you ever did **was + wreck** me

One of them *with **to*** but the other one *without **to***.

And Could we add **to** to the second sentence?

> All you ever did **was + (to) + wreck** me

Comment: This should be tagged to 'control verbs'.

Comment: Hi, PrisonPants, The first part of your question is identical to the question you asked before, [(be + to + verb) Grammar](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/304046/be-to-verb-grammar) and you need to include the link and explain why you are asking the same question again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is that the first uses "wanted", which takes a to-infinitive, not a bare infinitive.

The second uses "did", which takes a bare infinitive.

Having said that, "to" is possible in the second example, and I'm not sure why.

Comment: `All I wanted was  break your walls` is wrong?

Comment: It's not something that I would regard as grammatical.

Answer (score 0):

Simply be + to + verb means both HAVE TO, OUGHT TO and BE + VERB + ING.

HAVE TO : It means the person doesn't have any choice than doing it.

OUGHT TO : A suggestion or instruction

BE + VERB + ING : something that you are going to do in the future but it's planned and the day is known.

So be + to + verb are used ONLY in the above scenarios.

Examples

Future:
The train is going to arrive in the station in the next hour
NOW remove "going" 
The train is to arrive in the station in the next hour

Command:
You have to complete your assignments 
NOW replace "have to" with "are to"
You are to complete your assignments

Suggestion:
You ought to complete your new movie
NOW replace "ought to" with "are to"
You are to complete your new movie

Now for your question. No you can't use (to) because neither the sentences do satisfy the aforesaid scenarios.